# What causes DNS responses with an unknown ID?

Tags: dns, netty, vert.x

I'm using vert.x 3.7.1, which depends on netty 4.1.34.Final. HTTP requests are being made through vertx-web.

```java
WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);
HttpRequest<JsonArray> request = client.postAbs(uri)
    .timeout(timeout)
    .basicAuthentication(username, password)
    .as(BodyCodec.jsonArray());

// HttpRequest is created once and used for several requests.
request.sendJsonObject(bodyJson, handler);
```

Some times, netty logs the following warning. It repeats every 5 seconds with a different id and stops when DNS resolves, I believe.

```
WARNING [io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver] [id: 0xf9a6e215, L:/0.0.0.0:37175] Received a DNS response with an unknown ID: 38649
```

As I understand, netty generates a random id for the DNS query datagram and stores it as a key for the DNS query context in a map. When the DNS response datagram is received, the id is retrieved and checked against the map. When the DNS process finishes, the id is removed from the map.

What causes a DNS Response datagram to have an unknown id? Does that log indicate some problem? Should I take it as a regular event?

Comment: As far as I know this was fixed in Netty. Please upgrade to the latest stable release.

Comment: @NormanMaurer, thanks for your comment. I checked the latest milestones and noticed some dns related improvements. I will upgrade to the latest stable version.

Comment: @RafaelRocha did upgrading help? I also see the above prints with netty 4.1.34.Final and I wonder if upgrading netty helped.

Comment: @RomanBlachman, I can't confirm yet. The warnings only appear in our production environment and it has been impacting less than 0.1% of the requests. In these rare ocassions, the requests are getting delayed by an average of 10~20 secs. So we decided to wait for future releases of vert.x.